# JBPM 5 - Process Instance Variable Change Command

Tags: drools, jbpm

How to set/modify the process instance variables of a running process-instance in JBPM ?
Is there any pre-defined command class to set the process-instance-variables ?

I can see some commands like `org.drools.command.SetVariableCommandFromLastReturn` && 
 `org.drools.command.SetVariableCommandFromCommand`

Can I use these commands ? How to use this command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now I am updating the variables like this with `GenericCommand`.

```
kSession.execute(new GenericCommand<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean execute(Context context) {
                //Get session in the command context
                StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = ((KnowledgeCommandContext) context).getStatefulKnowledgesession();
                //Get the process instance
                ProcessInstance processInstance = (ProcessInstance) ksession.getProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
                //Get variable scoprts
                VariableScopeInstance variableScope = (VariableScopeInstance) processInstance.getContextInstance(VariableScope.VARIABLE_SCOPE);
                Iterator<String> piStateItr=piStateVariables.keySet().iterator();
                //Modify required variables
                while(piStateItr.hasNext()){
                    String variableName=piStateItr.next();
                    String variableValue=piStateVariables.get(variableName);
                    logger.debug(">>> Setting State - key "+variableName +" , to "+variableValue );
                    variableScope.setVariable(variableName, variableValue);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code, I'm facing the same problem. How are you retrieving the `processInstanceId` variable?

Comment: @ocramot , processInstanceId is input for the method enclosing given code.

Comment: Hi, can someone  please tell me if this works , as I tried this with jbpm 6.2 and outside session execute , the process variables have the old value after executing this also. I mean in my code after the session.execute is finished and outside this when i try to get the variable values  it still gives me the old values . please help.. !! its urgent !!